# Can't properly understand lambdas in Haskell

Tags: haskell, lambda, calculus

I have following code, implmenting inverse function calculation, basing on this formulas:

[image]

[image]

```
derivation :: (Fractional a) => (a -> a) -> (a -> a)
derivation f = \ x -> ( ( f (x + dx) - f (x) ) / dx ) where dx = 0.1

evalA k f
  | k == 0 =  \x -> x
  | otherwise = \x -> (derivation (evalA (k-1) f) x) / (derivation f x)

inverseFun f x =
 let
   x0 = 3.0
   eps = 0.001
   iter k prev sum =
    let       
      elemA = evalA k f x0
      elemB = prev * (x - (f x0)) / (if k == 0 then 1 else k)
      newItem = elemA * elemB
    in
      if abs (newItem) < eps
      then sum
      else iter (k + 1) elemB (sum + newItem)
  in
    iter 0 1.0 0.0


f1 = \x -> 1.0 * x * x

main = do
  print $ inverseFun f1 2.5
```

I need to optimise it by moving `evalA` inside the `inverseFun` and *store previous step calculation A'n/F' to reuse it on the next iteration, if possible*. As far as I understand, each time `evalA` returns some sort of function and **x** applies afterwards, right before declaring `elemA`.

How can I convert my `evalA` or rewrite it to store previous results (by passing these results in `iter`, obviously)?

Don't mind if this calculations are not too precise, it requires good `x0` and `eps` choice. My main question is in lambda conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change your definition of `inverseFun` such that the `(if k == 0 then 1 else k)` is instead `fromIntegral (if k == 0 then 1 :: Int else k)`, then you can provide type signatures to all of your functions:

```
derivation :: (Fractional a)        => (a -> a) -> a -> a
evalA      :: (Fractional a)        => Int -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
inverseFun :: (Fractional a, Ord a) => (a -> a) -> a -> a
f1         :: (Fractional a)        => a -> a
```

Which certainly helps out.

This is actually important for my solution to your problem, since we need `k` to be an `Int`, and you've used it as a `Fractional a => a`.  The `fromIntegral` fixes that, but it needs to know that it's an `Int`, so I just added the inline type signature to help the compiler along.

Since your function only depends on the previous single value, you can use our handy friend from `Prelude`, `iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]`.  This applies a function over and over again, producing an infinite list of values.  We can then index it at any point to get the desired result (this is why having `k` an `Int` is important!).

Our function will look like

```
evalA :: Fractional a => Int -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
evalA k f = iterate go id !! k
    where
        go = ???
```

Here `id` is the same as your base case of `\x -> x`, just shorter and with more optimization rules.  It serves as the initial value for generating this list.  To implement `go`, the actual computation, we need it to accept the previous result as its argument:

```
    where
        go prev = \x -> derivation prev x / derivation f x
```

But this is considered "poor style" by `hlint`, and so it is suggested to convert this to the form

```
    where
        go prev x = derivation prev x / derivation f x
```

And that's it!  I tested it and got the exact same result for your example input.  The full code can be viewed [here](https://gist.github.com/7fabf893b51a955986e4).

Comment: And instead of your `derivation` function you can use [ad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ad) to get the exact derivative of the function.

Comment: Thank you, @bheklilr for such detailed explanation.

Comment: I had to implement derivative calculation on my own